# convert this to japanese character (encoding)

Tags: php, unicode, encoding

Please help me convert this... I dont know how to call this kind of data, is it hex?

```
2%E6%9C%8819%E6%97%A5
```

I believe that this should be printed as 2月19日

How can I convert `2%E6%9C%8819%E6%97%A5` to be `2月19日` using PHP?

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like it's URL encoded http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Url_encoding

PHP UrlDecode might do the trick.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

There's an example at that link which shows url decoding the querystring of a page. I don't know PHP, but you might want soemthing like the following:

```
<?php
    $original = "2%E6%9C%8819%E6%97%A5";
    $decoded = urldecode($original);
    echo $decoded;
?>
```

Comment: Although, if you want it to render correctly in a browser, it might be wise to /html/ encode it before writing it to a page.

Comment: @Andrew M: That is not necessary if your are using the correct encoding (UTF-8).

Comment: @bn: What do you mean by _"it does not work"_? Are you getting no output? Are the characters displayed incorrectly? The `urldecode()` approach works for me.

Comment: @bn - Sorry, I've exhausted my PHP knowledge, someone else will have to have a look.

Comment: I dont know why it doesnt work. when I do urldecode("2%E6%9C%8819%E6%97%A5") it works but when i do urldecode($variable) it doesnt work

Comment: @bn, Ahh OK, could you post the whole code when it doesn't work with the $variable and also with the direct urldecode("2%E6%9C%8819%E6%97%A5")

Comment: @bn - i think u perform double decoded, just use `$variable` when u output the string, and your page encoding MUST be in UTF-8

Comment: i am trying to process this file : http://dammit.lt/wikistats/ try to download one. and try to get a line that begins with 'ja' using gzfile function and then put that line into $variable, and process it using urldecode(), it doesnt work... :(

Comment: @Bn, could you edit your original question and paste in the code you're running there?